# Problem with printing on Sql Report Server 2005 and WinXP updates

Tags: ssrs

We have installed and ruining MS SQL Report Server on WINSERV2003 and users access reports thought IE, recently I have more and more troubles making them able to print.
I know it is problem with one of MS updates (KB956803 KB956931), But lately and method for
uninstalling this two update does not help to IE start printing. Probably one of thees are integrated to service pack three.

My question is:  What I do need to do on server side to update server and avoid problem with installing ActiveX control on users IEs ?  Will after that those users which now able to print is going to have trouble?

Thank you in advance
Admir

Comment: You getting any errors showing up on clients such as 'Unable to load client print control' ?

Comment: Yes I am getting error 'Unable to load client print control' in IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would be helpful to have all the versions/builds/service packs of the systems involved.

Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/340151/reportviewer-client-print-control-unable-to-load-client-print-control/340346#340346) on StackOverflow that seems to have a fix that has been voted up a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The ReportViewer control uses ActiveX for printing in IE, and this is disabled by default for most sites in IE.  What you can do is put the site housing the report viewer control into the Trusted Sites section of IE so that it will allow ActiveX to use used for that site.

This is a setting that could be deployed centrally through Active Directory to all of your users.